# stereo_proc NO subscription so NO stereo_images

Tags: stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody

I was wondering if someone has ever seen something like that.

I'm using two uEye USB camera with a personnal arduino trigger.
Everything works fine. The calibration setup is OK.
But when I try to launch the stereo_proc node,
I can clearly see with rxgraph (or rosnode info) that stereo/proc as no subscriptions.
And according to the stereo_image_proc tutorial I should have

---

Subscriptions:

- /stereo/left/image_raw [sensor_msgs/Image]
- /stereo/left/camera_info [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo]
- /stereo/right/image_raw [sensor_msgs/Image]
- /stereo/right/camera_info [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo]

---

And I'm thinking that's why I can not go further with the my stereo bench.

Here is my launch file.

```
<launch>
 <!-- first camera and associated image pipeline -->

  <group ns="stereo_test" >
    <!-- left camera -->
        <node pkg="cameraUEYE" type="cameraUEYE_node" name="cameraUEYE_left_node" >
            <param name="guid" value="1" />
            <param name="frame_id" value="cam_left" />
            <param name="use_ros_time" value="true" />
            <param name="use_external_trigger" value="true" />
            <param name="frame_rate" value="50" />
                    <param name="camera_info_url" value="file:///home/vvittori/.ros/camera_info/UEYE_USB_1.yaml"/>
        <remap from="camera" to="left" />
        </node>
  <!-- right camera -->
        <node pkg="cameraUEYE" type="cameraUEYE_node" name="cameraUEYE_right_node" >
            <param name="guid" value="2" />
            <param name="frame_id" value="cam_right" />
            <param name="use_ros_time" value="true" />
            <param name="use_external_trigger" value="true" />
            <param name="frame_rate" value="50" />
                    <param name="camera_info_url" value="file:///home/vvittori/.ros/camera_info/UEYE_USB_2.yaml"/>
        <remap from="camera" to="right" />
        </node>
<!-- STEREO IMAGE PROC -->
<node pkg="stereo_image_proc" type="stereo_image_proc" respawn="false" name="proc" args="_approximate_sync:=True" />  
  </group>
  <!-- monitoring and configuration tools -->
  <node pkg="rxtools" type="rxconsole" name="rxconsole" />
  <node pkg="dynamic_reconfigure" type="reconfigure_gui"
        name="reconfigure_gui" /> 
</launch>
```

Any hints are welcomed !

Thanks

Regards

---

**EDIT :**

Thanks to Patrick I was able to understand that part in the wiki page ! (Cf. Patrick answer)
I was still block at the `rosnode info stereo/proc` results that they give us.

Anyway I've tried what he told me with the following command line (I have change stereo_test to stereo in my launch file)

```
ROS_NAMESPACE=stereo rosrun stereo_image_proc stereo_image_proc __name:=PROC
```

and

```
rosrun image_view stereo_view stereo:=/stereo image:=image_rect
```

as written in the wiki page.
Then, I did see what you told me that right after I launch the previous command it subscribed at

```
[ INFO] [1334565947.793592670]: Subscribing to:
    * /stereo/left/image_rect
    * /stereo/right/image_rect
    * /stereo/disparity
```

and yet I had the following error that occured :

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in Mat, file /tmp/buildd/libopencv-2.3.1+svn6514+branch23/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 303
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in Mat, file /tmp/buildd/libopencv-2.3.1+svn6514+branch23/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 303
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /tmp/buildd/libopencv-2.3.1+svn6514+branch23/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:303: error: (-215) 0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows in function Mat
Aborted
```

Do you know what it could be ?

Thanks

Regards

V.v

---

**EDIT 2 :**

Here is a bag file of the following topics when the OpenCV error occur. (sorry for the external link I don't have enough karma ... )
http://dl.free.fr/felDpzi5V

```
rosbag record -O stereo_proc_fail /stereo/right/camera_info /stereo/left/camera_info /stereo/left/image_raw /stereo/right/image_raw /stereo/left/image_rect /stereo/right/image_rect
```

Best Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31765/stereo_proc-no-subscription-so-no-stereo_images/) by [Vincent_V](https://answers.ros.org/users/2175/vincent_v/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2012-04-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-13**:
Shouldn't the  namespace be `stereo` and not `stereo_test`?

**Comment by [Vincent_V](https://answers.ros.org/users/2175/vincent_v/) on 2012-04-15**:
It was a "test" choice but I think that it is not a big deal as long as you specified it in the ROS_NAMESPACE . I maybe wrong I'll check it !

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-04-16**:
Are your camera_info and image sizes set properly? Could you include a short bagfile with your cameras streaming images and infos that reproduces that OpenCV assertion?

**Comment by [Vincent_V](https://answers.ros.org/users/2175/vincent_v/) on 2012-04-16**:
I don't know what properly set is for you ? Here is in the main post the bag file you ask . Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you subscribed to any of stereo_image_proc's advertised topics (e.g. `stereo_test/disparity`)? To avoid unnecessary computation (both in stereo_image_proc and the source camera driver nodes) it only subscribes on demand. From the [wiki docs](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stereo_image_proc#stereo_image_proc.2BAC8-common-1.stereo_image_proc):

> All processing is on demand. Color
> processing is performed only if there
> is a subscriber to a color topic.
> Rectification is performed only if
> there is a subscriber to a rectified
> topic. Disparities and point clouds
> are generated only if there is a
> subscriber to a relevant topic. While
> there are no subscribers to output
> topics, stereo_image_proc unsubscribes
> from the image_raw and camera_info
> topics.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2012-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figure out what was wrong according to my second update.

It was my driver that has something wrong.

I was setting roi.x_offset and roi.y_offset to 16 instead of 0 in order to have a 640x480 image instead of a 640x512.
But I forgot that with these cameras it's done automatically by the hardware of the cameras.

Thanks for the help.

---

Originally posted by [Vincent_V](https://answers.ros.org/users/2175/vincent_v/) with karma: 91 on 2012-04-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1